# How to use GroupBy in QueryOverride for Content Query Web Part in SharePoint 2016?

Tags: caml-query, content-query-web-part, 2016

I read a lot of forums, questions and answers and it looks like using GroupBy in QueryOverride is not taking in consideration. Here are the several ways I tried without success.

**Option 1**

```
<property name="QueryOverride" type="string">
<![CDATA[
    <GroupBy Collapse="TRUE" GroupLimit="30">
        <FieldRef Name="MonitoringType"/>
    </GroupBy>
</Query>]]></property>
```

**Option 2**

```
<property name="QueryOverride" type="string">
<[CDATA[
    <GroupBy Collapse="TRUE" GroupLimit="30">
        <FieldRef Name="MonitoringType"/>
    </GroupBy>
</Query>]]></property>
```

**Option 3**

```
<property name="QueryOverride" type="string">
<Query>
    <GroupBy Collapse="TRUE">
        <FieldRef Name="MonitoringType" Ascending="TRUE"/>
    </GroupBy>
</Query></property>
```

**Option 4**

```
<property name="QueryOverride" type="string">
&lt;![CDATA[
    &lt;GroupBy Collapse="TRUE" GroupLimit="30"&gt;
        &lt;FieldRef Name="MonitoringType"/&gt;
    &lt;/GroupBy>
&lt;/Query&gt;]]&gt;</property>
```

**Option 5**

```
<property name="QueryOverride" type="string">
&lt;[CDATA[
    &lt;GroupBy Collapse="TRUE" GroupLimit="30"&gt;
        &lt;FieldRef Name="MonitoringType"/&gt;
    &lt;/GroupBy>
&lt;/Query&gt;]]&gt;</property>
```

**Option 6**

```
<property name="QueryOverride" type="string">
&lt;GroupBy Collapse="TRUE" GroupLimit="30"&gt;
    &lt;FieldRef Name="MonitoringType"/&gt;
&lt;/GroupBy&gt;</property>
```

I'm sure I'm not so far but still not able figure out what doesn't work.

Many thanks for your help!